# Questions with long titles wrapping issue

Tags: bug

Consider the following question

[javascript select button and run it in new tab and wait 8sec and then do the same process again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465156/javascript-select-button-and-run-it-in-new-tab-and-wait-8sec-and-then-do-the-sam)

I noticed that the word "same" was split to "sa" and "me" on the next question. 
At first I thought it ways a typo, and I tried to edit that space in-between out. 
Then I realized, there is no space. The question title was too long, so it was split at a strange point.

When I tried to re-size my browser window, the title got smaller and smaller, but at the same time, it got split in the wrong places.

I think what is better for the title is to split only at `white-space` rather than at any arbitrary character.